# Multiple users in java DB (embeded)?

Tags: netbeans, javadb

Is it possible to create multiple users in Java DB (embeded) in NetBeans IDE? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean multiple database users, or do you mean having multiple JVM's connected to the database.

Comment: I mean multiple database users having one JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. It is described in the Derby development guide which is available on the Apache Derby website:

http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html

D